# using ahDoctrineEasyEmbeddedRelationsPlugin to embed i18n Translation

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4, symfony-forms

I'm using ahDoctrineEasyEmbeddedRelationsPlugin to add dynamic i18n translations to my object, so I wrote this in my object Form class

```
$this->embedRelations(array(
'Translation' => array( 
'considerNewFormEmptyFields' => array('content', 'lang')
));
```

The result I got is only one input per record, "content".

I've tried this in the FormTranslation class, but no luck:

```
$this->useFields(array('content', 'lang'));
```

So what I did was to create a manual doctrine relation with a foreignAlias called "translations", and then:

```
$this->embedRelations(array(
'translations' => array( 
'considerNewFormEmptyFields' => array('content', 'lang')
));
```

this almost worked, I get the lang field now, but only in the list of existing tranlations, not in the new translation form

Any ideas if I can archieve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hm , I always use for example for 'en' and 'uk' culture :

```
 considerNewFormEmptyFields' => array('en','uk')
```